# Frequency of element in sequence

Tags: probability

I am working with biological sequences and i'm stuck with this problem.

If the frequency of occurrence of alphabets A T G C  is 0.25 each.

If these alphabets (A, T , G , C) are arranged completely randomly. For them to maintain the frequency i.e 0.25 they have to be present 1 time in a sequence of 4 alphabets, 2 times in sequence of 8 alphabets and so on . .

Confusing part is how to know what is the expected value of it in sequence of 5 alphabets , or 3 alphabets or 25 alphabets etc

As alphabet cannot be present 1.25 times for sequence of 5 alphabets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're talking about the *expected* (i.e. *average*) frequency.  To illustrate, when we say *the average family has 2.3 children*, we don't expect to find children cut into thirds.

There are $4^5$ strings that can be made from the letters $\{A,C,G,T\}$.  There are $$\binom{5}{i} 3^{5-i}$$ that have exactly $i$ copies of the letter $A$ (or any other letter).

So, the total number of copies of $A$ in the $4^5$ strings is $$\sum_{i=0}^5 i \binom{5}{i} 3^{5-i}=1280.$$

Thus, the expected number of $A$'s in a $5$-letter string chosen uniformly at random would be $$\frac{1280}{4^5}=\frac{5}{4}.$$

This is unsurprising, since the probability that a random coordinate is $A$ is $\frac{1}{4}$ and there are $5$ coordinates whose letters are independent.  So [linearity of expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity) gives us $$\mathrm{E}(\text{number of } A \text{s})=\sum_j \mathrm{E}(I_j(A))=\frac{\text{nr positions}}{4}$$ where $j$ is a position and $I_j(A)$ is the [indicator function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) that there is an $A$ in position $j$.

Comment: I am not concerned about A's in a given position, I am concerned about average number of A's in a seq. i.e for a 4 letter word "ABCD" frequency of A is 0.25 which is similar to observed. For a 8 letter word "AABBCCDD" frequency of A is again 0.25 which agrees with the observed. So what is the expected frequency of A in sequence of say length 6. Because any whole number divided by 6 cannot give 0.25. So how can we say the sequence is arranged completely randomly (i.e all have frequency of 0.25 ) and have no bias to specific letters {A, B, C , D}.(Note: Some thing other than Monte-Carlo method).

Comment: For e.g. AABCDD, the number of A's in this sequence is 2.  The average here is the proportion of A's in the sequence (=2/6).  If we randomly generate a sequence, then we have another average: the average over all possible sequences.  So, the average proportion of A's would be 6/4.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the word "alphabet" when you mean "letter." Anyway, the expected value of a random variable does not have to be a possible value of the random variable; it is just the average value. A Bernoulli variable that is zero or one with probability 1/2 has expected value 1/2, for instance.